# tableview and UIButton on the same view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uibutton, tableview

I have a view that contains tableview and button.  My screen looks like below

```
-----------------


tableview



-----------------
UIButton
-----------------
```

However, UIButton doesn't come up.  I mean, that entire section of the screen is just white and nothing is drawn.

Is tableview preventing that UIButton to showup?

Comment: Add some code please. Code that adding UITableView and UIButton to your main view

Comment: I'm using IB in Xcode 4.  I added the tableview and UIButton using IB.

Only code is just setting up properties and connect them to objects in IB using ctrl drag.

Initially, I didn't have any IBOutlet properties either.  just to run it to see if these objects would come up but only thing comes up fine is the tableview and UIButton is not shown at all.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` most likely overlaying `UIButton`. Do you see both table and button in Interface Builder? If you do, try to make a new project from "View-based application" template, go to the second xib file (*ProjecNameViewController.xib*) in your project (**not to MainWindow.xib**, don't touch this file), carefully drag `UITableView` into the `UIView`, change size of `UITableView` for smaller (by default it fill all available space of `UIView`), add `UIButton` under the `UITableView`. Don't do anything else. Launch project. If you can see all controls - try to add connections and other stuff. Maybe you'll catch a step when you do it wrong. Good luck!

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I see tableview and uibutton in the IB but not on running app...  didn't try your method exactly but tried to create the brand new view controller with xib but still the same thing... 

I'm not sure if it's because tableview is overlaying the button because the scroll bar on the tableview does not go into UIButton area at all.

strange...

Comment: did you check the resizing masks for tableview and the Button ?

Comment: Just try to do as I said. That will show you what's going wrong

Comment: okay. @Sharrp, I will try that Sharrp. Will let you know. @Rahul, I'm pretty sure the resizing mask is fine on both. Like I said, I can see the scroll bar in the tableview and it doesn't go over to uibutton area at all. but who knows, I will double check. Thank you all!